# setVisible is not a function google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to make something to where you can set the radius of in which you see the markers or not. But it keeps on giving the error: currentMarker.setVisible is not a function.

My code is as the following:

```
function calcDistance(marker){
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
        pos.latlng = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };  
        var currentMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat,marker.lng)
        var currentPos = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.latlng.lat, pos.latlng.lng)
        var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(currentMarker, currentPos);
        console.log((distance/1000).toFixed(2));
        if(distance/1000 > radius){
            currentMarker.setVisible(false);
        }
        else {
            currentMarker.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

The function gets called everytime a marker is made, which would be the following code:

```
 for (i = 0; i < $winkels.length; i++) { 
    marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng($winkels[i].lat, $winkels[i].lng),
        map: map,
        latlng: {lat: $winkels[i].lat, lng: $winkels[i].lng}
    });
   calcDistance(marker[i].latlng);
}
```

Comment: what does return new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat,marker.lng) ?

Comment: This converts the objects into a google maps marker object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set visible is a method attached to `new google.maps.Marker({})` you are trying to call setVisible on a google lat-lng point.

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  }).setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Yes thank you! this must be it